# How to make a custom progress bar in swift, iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I want to fill black color to `UIView`, based on percentage (10%, 30% 50%...)?
[image]

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You will need more than a UIView. You will need to create a UIView subclass and implement the appropriate code in `drawRect`

Comment: My best guess are you making a progress bar?

Comment: create a view and inside it a subview with the width proportionally to the parent view, and if its a progress bar you can animate the width change

Answer (score 7):

If it is a custom progress bar you are looking for , Try this :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewProg: UIView! // your parent view, Just a blank view


let viewCornerRadius : CGFloat = 5
var borderLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let progressLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewProg.layer.cornerRadius = viewCornerRadius
    drawProgressLayer()

}


func drawProgressLayer(){

   let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewProg.bounds, cornerRadius: viewCornerRadius)
   bezierPath.closePath()
   borderLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
   borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
   borderLayer.strokeEnd = 0
   viewProg.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)


}

//Make sure the value that you want in the function `rectProgress` that is going to define 
//the width of your progress bar must be in the range of
// 0 <--> viewProg.bounds.width - 10 , reason why to keep the layer inside the view with some border left spare.
//if you are receiving your progress values in 0.00 -- 1.00 range , just multiply your progress values to viewProg.bounds.width - 10 and send them as *incremented:* parameter in this func

func rectProgress(incremented : CGFloat){

    print(incremented)
    if incremented <= viewProg.bounds.width - 10{
        progressLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        let bezierPathProg = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(5, 5, incremented , viewProg.bounds.height - 10) , cornerRadius: viewCornerRadius)
        bezierPathProg.closePath()
        progressLayer.path = bezierPathProg.CGPath
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        borderLayer.addSublayer(progressLayer)

    }

  }
}
```

PS:- What you are trying to do can also be achieved by a line defined with some particular point as start and end points , set the lines `lineWidth` accordingly and then animates its **strokeEnd** but finding the points is a huge pain(because you need to know the frame size of the screen to then navigate to the view and so on... i'm not saying you cant) so i would prefer this,

Comment: Accept and +1 this answer if it solved your issue :) Happy coding

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways of doing it.

1. Create subclass of UIView and in `drawRect` method paint exact area
   that you need.
2. Add new `UIView` object(which is white one on your image) yo your view(which is black one).